# How to get a String from HTTP and use it to build a JSON Object?

Tags: java, android, json, network-programming

I try to get a String (a JSON file in reality) from a HTTP server to store data about a Twitch stream.

The String I got by connecting : [api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/lainkk](http://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/lainkk)

I would like to get this String in a String variable and to build a JSON object from this String.

I wrote some methods but I always got a SystemErr in the log while calling those methods:

This is my own Twitch API class :

```
package com.linkpulsion.bibix;

import android.util.Log;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class Twitch {
    private String channel;
    public final static String TWITCH_API_SERVER = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/";

/**
 * Constructor of Java Twitch API Json Generator
 * @param channel The cannel name to get the infos
 */
public Twitch(String channel){
    if(channel != null){
        this.channel = channel;
    }
}

/**
 * Getter for channel name
 * @return String the channel name
 */
public String getChannel(){
    return this.channel;
}

protected String getJson(String mode){
    String apiUri = TWITCH_API_SERVER + mode + "/" + this.channel;
    try{
        URL website = new URL(apiUri);
        URLConnection connection = website.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            response.append(inputLine);
        in.close();
        return response.toString();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

protected JSONObject buildJSON(String jsonRaw){
    JSONObject json = null;
    try{
        json = new JSONObject(jsonRaw);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return json;
}

public void isSreaming(){
    String jsonRaw = getJson("streams");
    Log.d(null,"RETOUR " + jsonRaw);
}
}
```

Thank you !

Comment: Where are you calling your `getJson()` method? What exact error are you getting?  NetworkOnMainThreadException perhaps?

Comment: I call my getJson() in another activity through a "Refresh" button.
The error I get is "13931-13931/? W/System.err﹕ at com.linkpulsion.bibix.Twitch.getJson(Twitch.java:46)"

Line 46 is when I create the BuffreredReader, after openning connection.

Comment: Are you using a background Thread or an AsyncTask? Or are you trying to run it on the main UI Thread?  Also, do you have the `INTERNET` permission in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: I try to run it on the main UI Thread.

Comment: Well, that's not going to work.  Do you see NetworkOnMainThreadException anywhere in your logs?  Show the code that calls the getJson() method in your on click code for the Refresh button.

Comment: The code that call the getJson() is in the onOptionsItemSelected() and is :
'if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
            System.out.println("REFRESHING");
            twitch.isSreaming();
            return true;
        }'
I did not see any NetworkOnMainThreadException in the log.

Comment: The whole log from starting th app to clicking the Refresh button : http://pastebin.com/x7SrdHAB

Comment: So to make this piece of code properly, I have to run it in a separate Thread ? How can I do that ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83594/discussion-between-daniel-nugent-and-cyprien-aubry).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your original code and got a NetworkOnMainThreadException.

I made a simple AsyncTask, and it worked:

```
private class TwitchAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String str = twitch.getJson("streams");
        return str;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "result: " + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //testing buildJSON:
        JSONObject obj = twitch.buildJSON(result);

        Log.d("JSON Result: ",  obj.toString());
    }
}
```

Here's the full class I used to test with:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Twitch twitch;
    JSONObject jsonObj;  //instance variable which can be accessed anywhere in the class code

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        twitch = new Twitch("aksynial");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

            System.out.println("REFRESHING");
            new TwitchAsync().execute();

            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class TwitchAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String str = twitch.getJson("streams");
            return str;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "result: " + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //testing buildJSON:
            //assign to the instance variable jsonObj
            jsonObj = twitch.buildJSON(result);

            Log.d("JSON Result: ",  jsonObj.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Log result in `onPostExecute()`:

```
 D/JSON Result:﹕ {"_links":{"channel":"https:\/\/api.twitch.tv\/kraken\/channels\/aksynial","self":"https:\/\/api.twitch.tv\/kraken\/streams\/aksynial"},"stream":null}
```

Comment: And how can I recover the JSONObject to filter the data in another method in Twitch.java for example ?

Comment: @CyprienAubry If you need the JSONObject in a method in Twitch.java, just pass it into the method as a parameter.  You could keep the JSONObject reference in the Activity as an instance variable.  I just updated the Activity code, take a look.

Comment: I get the same error (SysErr) when I call JSONObject.get(String s)